# Excel - Display only the integer as though FLOOR was used, but keep decimal data for other formulas

Tags: excel, custom-formatting

I have a collection of values that almost never are complete whole numbers, but instead have the tenths place to some degree (i.e. 1000.8, 2049.3, etc). When displaying these values, I want Excel (2010) to show only the completed integer values, but not round them up (default behavior, doesn't appear I can change it). I need those fractional values to be kept for other formulas in the workbook, but I just don't want them displayed. Here's an example:

```
       A            B               C           D
    --+---------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | True Val    Display Val     Formula     Calculated
    2 | 1000.9      1000            =B2*3       3002.7
    3 | 2049.3      2049            =B3*3       6147.9
    4 | 515433.5    515433          =B4*3       1546300.5
```

What I want to see in these cells is what I have shown in Column B above, but the actual data held in those cells is what I have shown in Column A, and the result of a calculation I expect to see is shown in Column D (using formulas from Column C).

I have searched for hours, but everything I come across just doesn't accomplish what I'm looking for.

Please understand that I am **NOT** trying to use the TRUNC() or ROUNDDOWN() formula functions on these cells, as this would remove the fractional data, and my formulas would be using incorrect data during calculations. This is a purely cosmetic format I am looking for, so I can see whole numbers that have been completed, without seeing the decimals, and no rounding to an invalid integer. Again, the proper solution **does not** have Cell B2 multiplied by 3 result in 3000.

The closest I have figured out is to have these mirrored in another column where I have rounded-down/truncated the data, but this creates an unnecessary column I wish to avoid if possible. If there is no way to do this via custom formatting, altering the rounding method used in the sheet, or some other way, then I will be forced to add another column just for this.

Comment: Will you accept a ***VBA*** solution??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, I'd like to see a VBA solution!.. can't think how that would work??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I won't object to a VBA answer if it is the only recourse to effectively solve this conundrum, but keep in mind that it must not recalculate the cells nor interfere with the cell data itself. As I am about to comment below on the current answer, the cells I want to display in this manner are actually calculated results from a search on another sheet, which in turn were generated by a data query JSON object from PowerQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If the cells in question contain **constants**, *(not formulas)* and there are not a large number of these cells, then select the cells and run this macro:

```
Sub FakeFormatNoDots()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    Dim r As Range

    DQ = Chr(34)

    For Each r In Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(2)
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, ".") > 0 Then
            mesage = DQ & Split(v, ".")(0) & DQ
            r.NumberFormat = mesage & ";" & mesage & ";" & mesage & ";"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

**NOTES:**

This is **not** a good general solution because there are a limited number of Custom Formats that Excel can handle.

If you change the values, you must:

1. clear the formats
2. re-run the macro.

Comment: better than nothing! +1

Comment: Well, this solution might work well for constants, but my cells are actually formulas that get their data from other cells in another sheet in the workbook. The source of the data begins as a JSON object from a webpage that is obtained by PowerQuery, which generates a data collection table in its own sheet. The sheet I am trying to modify the display on performs a search on a specified column in the source sheet (the query table result), and returns the appropriate cell adjacent to the match (which is a float with tenths precision).

Comment: Cont.:  I need to not impede the formulas or lose the float data as this sheet is a static reference point for many other sheets that calculate results using this data. I don't have the other sheets reference the query sheet because the order is subject to change frequently, and I don't wish to copy the MATCH() formula several hundred times over when I can just point it to a cell in the main sheet that doesn't change its order and performs the MATCH itself for all the data points (there are 27 right now, and likely more to be added in the future).

Comment: @user253780  In that case, my solution should be ignored.............sorry.........